# Erro na Function Generic para o retorno da Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou tentando fazer um método Genérico para retorno de procedure, mas ao pegar a DataRow para fazer um Cast gera o seguinte erro:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type
>   'ClasseParaGerar'.

Estou utilizando um Operador de Tipo de Conversão

```
public class Pesquisa
    {
        public string NOME { get; set; }
        public string IDADE { get; set; }

        public static explicit operator Pesquisa(DataRow model)
        {
            if (model == null)
                return null;

            var result = new Pesquisa();

            try
            {
                if(model["NOME"] != null)
                    result.NOME = model["NOME"].ToString();

                if (model["IDADE"] != null)
                    result.IDADE = model["IDADE"].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Como posso fazer essa conversão automática?

```
public List<TEntity> ExecuteCommandGeneric<TEntity>(string procName, SqlParameter[] Parametros, CommandType commandType)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(StrConnecting))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand { Connection = connection, CommandText = procName, CommandType = commandType })
                    {
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                        if (!(Parametros == null))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; (i <= (Parametros.Length - 1)); i++)
                            {

                                if (Parametros[i].Value != null)
                                    if (!VerificaSeguranca(Parametros[i].Value.ToString()))
                                        throw new Exception("Erro 171 - Contate o Suporte!");
                                command.Parameters.Add(Parametros[i]);
                            }
                        }

                        connection.Open();

                        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", procName);
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

            List<TEntity> listGeneric= dt.Rows.Cast<TEntity>().ToList();

            return listGeneric;
        }
```

Comment: sim, como o cast irá saber qual coluna mapear para qual propriedade da classe? isso tem de ser feito manualmente. Considere também usar um framework pra ajudar, como *Automapper* por exemplo, tem vários que podem ajudar a simplificar

Comment: Um código desnecessário para esse contexto, e que pode ocasionar baixo desempenho pelas estruturas utilizadas ... !!!

Comment: Ricardo Pontual você conhece o explicit operator ou o implicit operator? Quando vc precisa fazer alguma validação desse tipo, você pode utilizar um operador de conversão de tipo, neste caso quero utilizar este operador e é nesse caso que o erro ocorre.

Comment: O cast só será automático se o retorno da procedure coincidir as colunas, tipos e ordem com os atributos da classe